# Multicol doesn't break formulas

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, line-breaking, multicol

When trying to create a 3-column document (with tight-spaced page paddings), the text is in place, however, the formulas are not adapted to the column width:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
The following equation shows ...
\mathcal{L}(q)=E_{q(\tau)}[\log p(\tau)]+E_{q(\theta)}[\log p(\theta)]+E_{q(\mathbf{z}) q(\tau)}[\log p(\mathbf{z} | \tau)]
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
The following equation shows ...
\mathcal{L}(q)=E_{q(\tau)}[\log p(\tau)]+E_{q(\theta)}[\log p(\theta)]+E_{q(\mathbf{z}) q(\tau)}[\log p(\mathbf{z} | \tau)]
\end{align}

\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can equations also adapted to the columns?

Comment: unrelated to multicolumn, there is no automatic line breaking in `align` the point of the environment is that you need to add `\\ ` to break the equation as needed.

Comment: it is hard to suggest anything without a real example, presumably your real document does not have `The following equation shows ...` _inside_ the math

Comment: Is this also the case when using $ ...$?

Comment: no inline math will break in some places, but that looks more suitable to display math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext

The following equation shows \ldots
\begin{multline}
\mathcal{L}(q)=E_{q(\tau)}[\log p(\tau)]+\\
E_{q(\theta)}[\log p(\theta)]+\\
E_{q(\mathbf{z}) q(\tau)}[\log p(\mathbf{z} | \tau)]
\end{multline}

\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```